# Set op ViewPager inside ASyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I'm trying to get some data within a ASyncTask and once it completes pass that data to any fragments inside a viewpager. But I get the following exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewPager has not been bound.

I have to following code:

```
OnCreateView
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        setContentView(R.layout.simple_tabs);       
        team_id = this.getIntent().getIntExtra("index", 0) + 1;
        new getTeam().execute();
    }
```

ASyncTask:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        team = api.getTeamByID(team_id);
        return null;       
    }

@Override  
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            mAdapter = new TeamFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
            mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

TeamFragmentAdapter:

```
class TeamFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TitleProvider {

        ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        ArrayList<String> titels = new ArrayList<String>();

        public TeamFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            fragments.add(new TeamInformatieFragment(team));
            titels.add("Informatie");               
            fragments.add(new ContactFragment());
            titels.add("Informatie");
        }



        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getTitle(int position) {
            return titels.get(position);
        }
    }
```

When I move the contents of "OnPostExecute(Void result)" to OnCreateView it works... But I have to get all the data before the fragments are created.

Could you tell me what's going wrong? :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FIXED! I had to move all the layout-stuff to the OnPostExecute from ASyncTask.
It looks like this:

```
@Override  
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            setContentView(R.layout.simple_tabs);

            mAdapter = new TeamFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
            mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Comment: dont understand it, but it seems to work :/ ? any explanation here?

Comment: @cV2 yes, because it's changing layout, so it must be run on UI Thread, AsyncTask's onPostExecute is UIThread. :)

Comment: yeah, thanks for the response, but why doesn't it work to set the UI in onCreate, and just make adaptions in onPostExecute()...
why to set the complete layout in onPostExecute? (that was the real question) :) looking forward to your answer